# Error when calling Web API with self-hosted Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I am using a new Azure Service Fabric project. The project contains 2 statefull services as shown in the below image:

[image: Solution tree in Visual Studio]

When I run the application, the explorer is shown successfully as below:

[image: Service Fabric Explorer]

But when I try to hit my API, http://localhost:19080/api/values, I get the below `Invalid argument` error. It does not hit the controller:

[image: Invalid argument error message]

Kindly advise how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LoekD mentioned, port 19080 is used by the Service Fabric explorer. You can find the actual port of your application in ServiceManifest.xml of API project. There should be the section Resources with Endpoints like:

```
<Resources>
 <Endpoints>
   <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="8315" />
 </Endpoints>
</Resources>
```

Comment: An Endpoint configuration is not required to use Kestrel. And it uses dynamic port as mentioned in the article. To use dynamic port assignment with Kestrel, simply omit the Endpoint configuration in ServiceManifest.xml entirely, and do not pass an endpoint name to the KestrelCommunicationListener.  So how i can get this dynamic port number

Comment: @HanyHabib Why would you need dynamic port?

Comment: I dont need to i am just digging in this framework and see its capabilities. I used static port as u mentioned it didn't work unless i change ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl to ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None .

Comment: Now I see what you mean. To get dynamic port you need to use Naming Service to resolve endpoint of your service. Though I doubt that it can be accessed from outside SF. It should look like `var resolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();
var cancellationToken = new System.Threading.CancellationToken();
var endpoint = await resolver.ResolveAsync(new Uri(“<name of your service>”), new ServicePartitionKey(), cancellationToken);`

Answer (score 1):

Port 19080 is used by the [Service Fabric explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-visualizing-your-cluster). 
You should choose a [different port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint) to run your own service on.

Comment: An Endpoint configuration is not required to use Kestrel. And it uses dynamic port as mentioned in the article. To use dynamic port assignment with Kestrel, simply omit the Endpoint configuration in ServiceManifest.xml entirely, and do not pass an endpoint name to the KestrelCommunicationListener.

Comment: So how i can get this dynamic port number ?